# How to hide stderr without "muting" user input

Tags: command-line, bash

To put it simply, I have a script that uses `read -e` to grab user input, but because of the environment, lots of 'broken pipe' messages pop up and pollute the display. I wanted to hide stderr, so I tried this:

```
main 2>/dev/null
```

Which *works*, per se, I'm able to give input, and the broken pipe errors are as good as gone. However, apparently this method is how password entry works, because it mutes my input. **I cannot see what I am typing.**

Is it possible to redirect the streams in such a way that I can mute stderr without muting the input?  I'm guessing `read` is using stderr to deliver the prompt, which might make this impossible, but it doesn't hurt to ask.

For the sake of argument, the script is designed to run in said environment, and I can't simply change to a different one.

---

As for `main`, it's a function that handles I/O with the user and calls other functions. Here's a simplified version:

```
main(){
  while true; do
    get_input $(get_completions)
    [ $choice == "d" ] && fn_delete; continue
    [ $choice == "vwr" ] && fn_change_vwr_command; continue
    [ ... ]
  done
}
```

It works fine by itself. It's when I run `main 2>/dev/null` that the errors go away and my input is muted.

---

## Edit

This has been solved. The fix is to redirect read's stderr to its stdout with `2>&1`.

See, this is why I like to make a single "input-getter" function whenever dealing with user input. For me, implementing the aforementioned patch was as simple as editing a single line in `get_input()`

Comment: What 'broken pipe' errors occur, and what is the relevant code for the function etc?

Comment: grep, sort and cat are generating them. As for the function, it's a commandline/prompt driver, i.e. all it does is fetch user input and then delegate it to another function, it has a bunch of lines like `[ $choice == "d" ] && qw_delete`. I realize this is a silly thing to program in bash, where Python or Perl would probably be more suitable, but I'm already 700 lines in, and I like bash for its ubiquity and for its simplicity when it comes to interfacing with the OS.

Comment: @Wilf Just so you know, I'm only curious if this is possible or not, the script works fine in a normal pts/tty shell, it's when I run it from within  dvtm (a minimalistic multiplexer that's actually quite nice) that these broken pipes happen. Is this what `dtach` is for?

Comment: Am I obligated to link to the [script](https://gitlab.com/bradenbest/shell-scripts/raw/master/scripts/qwatch/qwatch)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redirect `read`'s `stderr` to `stdout`:

```bsh
read -p "Input: " x 2>&1
```

`script.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Input: " x 2>&1
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: So read *does* use stderr. This patch works perfectly. Thank you, sir! Now I can use my script in dvtm without being harassed by random broken pipes. It appears dvtm is somehow delaying the kernel's routine SIGPIPEs from getting to the pipelines. Should I report this to the developer as a bug?

Comment: @B1KMusic I don't even know what you're talking about, so I'll limit myself to provide the workaround above!

Comment: Workaround? Your solution is excellent. It's elegant, and does exactly what I needed.